# err_cert_authority_invalid - self signed CA is invalid on android, but works on PC

Tags: android, ssl, ca

I'm testing https webserver and have an issue while trying to access it from my android phone.

- software used: Google Chrome and wrapped into WebView version of the site;
- devices: google pixel 3a running android 10, android studio emulator w/ android 8.

Step performed:

1. Using this script: [Getting Chrome to accept self-signed localhost certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580508/getting-chrome-to-accept-self-signed-localhost-certificate/54816026#54816026), I generated certs and keys for my server to access it via IP: `192.168.0.101` (in script replaced DNS alt_name with IP);
2. Ran golang (also tried nodejs) webserver with followed cert/key pair:
   `http.ListenAndServeTLS("192.168.0.101:8443", "/home/username/ssl/192.168.0.101.crt", "/home/username/ssl/192.168.0.101.key", router)`
3. Added `myCA.pem` as the trusted authority in desktop Google Chrome and it works;
4. Added the same `myCA.pem` as the trusted authority in android cert storage, tried to reboot chrome/device but it's still invalid.

[Not sure is it important but this is how it looks on PC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcTMd.png)

[And on Android phone under User tab in Trusted Credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JjMvi.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feels like I did something wrong with the Server Cert (but error referred to CA) and/or CA and I have no idea why it was worked on PC.

I have recreated all certs with followed settings:

```
CN=localhost
[alt_names]
IP.1=127.0.0.1
IP.2=192.168.0.101
IP.3=<external_ip_here_to_check_from_the_web>
```

And it works fine on both platforms.